# If a self-adjoint Hilbert space operator is the strong limit of finite rank operators, must it be compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T:H \to H$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space H. Suppose there is a sequence $(T_n)$ of finite rank operators that converge strongly (but not necessarily in norm) to $T$. Must $T$ be compact?

Strong convergence: $\|T_n(x) - T(x)\| \to 0$ for each $x \in H$.

Comment: $T=I$, $T_n(x)=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,0,0,...)$ on $\ell^{2}$ is an obvious counter-example.

Comment: Indeed. The sloppiness of the textbook I am reading strikes again.... Thanks for the nice counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The strong closure of the finite-rank operators is all of $B(H)$. This follows easily from von Neumann's Double Commutant Theorem.

If you want a concrete counterexample the canonical way is the one mentioned by Kavi Rama Murthy, that the identitiy is a strong limit of finite-rank projections. That fact can also be used to show that the finite-rank operators are dense in $B(H)$. Namely, let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of finite-rank projections such that $P_n\to I$ strongly. Then, for any $T\in B(H)$ we have
$$
Tx=\lim_nP_nTx,
$$
so that $T=\lim P_nT$, where $P_nT$ is finite-rank for all $n$.